# getting error when running ndk-build i cygwin

Tags: android, windows, android-ndk, vuforia

when i trying to running the command code ndk-build ,the error prompt out like this

leo@leo-PC /cygdrive
$ ndk-build
/bin/sh: NUL: No such file or directory
Error: Current working directory is a virtual Cygwin directory which does
not exist for a native Windows application.
Can't start native Windows application from here.

make: execvp: /cygdrive/c/Users/leo/Desktop/android/android-ndk-r9d/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/awk.exe: Not a directory
Android NDK: Host 'awk' tool is outdated. Please define NDK_HOST_AWK to point to Gawk or Nawk !
/cygdrive/c/Users/leo/Desktop/android/android-ndk-r9d/build/core/init.mk:377: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.

i had following all the step here https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/step-1-setting-development-environment-android-sdk  and also crated the windows path for them but i still facing this problem .

Comment: cygwin is no longer needed to build for the ndk. Have you tried running ndk-build from a Windows command prompt?